# Using SQLite as a file cache

Tags: sqlite

My C++ application needs to support caching of files downloaded from the network. I started to write a native LRU implementation when someone suggested I look at using SQLite to store an ID, a file blob (typically audio files) and the the add/modify datetimes for each entry.

I have a proof of concept working well for the simple case where one client is accessing the local SQLite database file.

However, I also need to support multiple access by different processes in my application as well as support multiple instances of the application - all reading/writing to/from the same database.

I have found a bunch of posts to investigate but I wanted to ask the experts here too - is this a reasonable use case for SQLite and if so, what features/settings should I dig deeper into in order to support my multiple access case.

Thank you.

M.

Comment: Relational databases, in general, are designed to be used by multiple processes.  Just be sure to commit your insert / update / delete transactions, and read committed rows.

Comment: Thank you Gilbert - are you referring to bracketing the SQL statements I piece together with `BEGIN_TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` before I sent them to sqlite3_exec() to be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I also need to support multiple access by different processes in my application as well as support multiple instances of the application - all reading/writing to/from the same database.

SQLite can definitely support this use case. The main point here is that you have multiple readers and writers. SQLite's [WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) supports concurrent multiple readers and single writer. So in your application, just make sure to have one connection that is dedicated to writing, and one or more connections (i.e. a connection pool) dedicated to reading. This is actually a really common pattern even for scalable replicated database servers.

The only real point of contention would be between multiple running instances of the application all trying to write at the same time. If you can designate a single instance as the 'writer' and route all write requests to that one, it will take care of the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Most filesystems are in effect databases too, and most store two or more timestamps for each file, i.e. related to the last modification and last access time allowing implementation of an LRU cache.  Using the filesystem directly will make just as efficient use of storage as any DB, and perhaps more so.  The filesystem is also already geared toward efficient and relatively safe access by multiple processes (assuming you follow the rules and algorithms for safe concurrent access in a filesystem).

The main advantage of SQLite may be a slightly simpler support for sorting the list of records, though at the cost of using a separate query API.  Of course a DB also offers the future ability of storing additional descriptive attributes without having to encode those in the filename or in some additional file(s).

Comment: Thanks for that insight Greg and agreed on the second paragraph.  The piece I was hoping SQLite might help me with was having to deal with multiple threads/processes trying to access the files simultaneously - I would have to do that on my own if the files were stored directly in the file system but I hoped SQLite would do much of the work for me.

Comment: As I hinted, there are some fairly well known algorithms for safely allowing multiple processes/threads to create and remove shared files concurrently.  SQLite will possibly help by reducing the complexity here, but possibly at the expense of some performance since with the filesystem every process making modifications is entirely independent and not being serialized by DB transactions.